# What is the replacement for TokenStore, TokenServices and JwtAccessTokenConverter in Spring Security 5

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am upgrading Spring Boot from 2.3.12.RELEASE to 2.7.7 in my Kotlin project and found out that I have to change the code for Spring Security because Spring Security OAuth that was used in this project is no longer supported and has to be migrated to Spring Security 5+. I have this configuration that I want to migrate (some business data omitted):

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
class ResourceServerConfig : ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter() {

    @Value("...")
    private val claimAud: String? = null

    @Value("...")
    private val urlJwk: String? = null

    override fun configure(resources: ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer) {
        resources.tokenStore(tokenStore())
        resources.resourceId(claimAud)
    }

    @Bean
    fun tokenStore(): TokenStore {
        logger.info("JWK settings resource config: $urlJwk")
        return JwkTokenStore(urlJwk, createJwtAccessTokenConverter())
    }

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http.anonymous().and().cors(withDefaults())
            .authorizeRequests()
            .mvcMatchers(BASE_PATH_PATTERN).permitAll()
            .mvcMatchers(API_PATH_PATTERN).permitAll()
            .mvcMatchers(ADMIN_PATH_PATTERN).authenticated()
    }

    @Bean
    fun securityEvaluationContextExtension(): SecurityEvaluationContextExtension {
        return SecurityEvaluationContextExtension()
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    fun tokenServices(): DefaultTokenServices {
        val defaultTokenServices = DefaultTokenServices()
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore())
        return defaultTokenServices
    }

    @Bean
    fun createJwtAccessTokenConverter(): JwtAccessTokenConverter? {
        val converter = JwtAccessTokenConverter()
        converter.accessTokenConverter = MyTokenConverter()
        return converter
    }
```

```
@Component
class MyTokenConverter : DefaultAccessTokenConverter(), JwtAccessTokenConverterConfigurer {
    override fun extractAuthentication(claims: Map<String?, *>?): OAuth2Authentication {
        val authentication = super.extractAuthentication(claims)
        authentication.details = claims
        return authentication
    }

    override fun configure(converter: JwtAccessTokenConverter) {
        converter.accessTokenConverter = this
    }
}
```

I don't know what to do with those methods related to TokenStore, TokenServices or TokenConverter, how to replace them.

I consulted the migrtation guide https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Migration-Guide but it seems that it lacks a lot of information, there is no specific guide anywhere actually for how to replace those components that I mentioned in my question.

Comment: Side note: Upgrading all the way to Spring Security 6.0 before updating to 5.8 is not recommended. The Spring Security team has put together a migration guide to go from 5.8 to 6, before several defaults change and several breaking changes are introduced. https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/index.html - Please consider going from 5.3 (aligned with Boot 2.3) to 5.8 first.

Comment: I think that https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Migration-Guide#examples-matrix-1 is what you are looking for. Check out the JWT + JWK example specifically.

Comment: Other than that, I think you are looking for `JwtAuthenticationConverter` to replace `JwtAccessTokenConverter`.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I tried to upgrade to 3.0.1 but realized it requires Java upgrade too, so instead, I'll upgrade to Spring Boot 2.7.7 (will edit the question).

Comment: Hi, did you figure out how to do this migration?